# Is there any update in stackexchange site?

Tags: discussion, user-interface

I can see the change in UI of stackexchange today. Very happy to see that. Is there any update in the features too ?

Comment: For network-wide changes, I think you will get more and faster information at meta.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the mobile theme [has been updated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234717/259867). Feel free to weigh in in that thread if you found bugs or have suggestions for further improvement.

This update only changes the mobile layout, not the functionality of the site.